# stuck on this C code

Tags: c, unix

OK so the purpose of this code is to Prompt user for an integer then
the program will print out each digit 0-9 and it number of occurrence in the user provided number. 
the output is supposed to look something like this

```
Enter a number: 28666

0 is repeated 0 times.
1 is repeated 0 times.
2 is repeated 1 times.
3 is repeated 0 times.
4 is repeated 0 times.
5 is repeated 0 times.
6 is repeated 3 times.
7 is repeated 0 times.
8 is repeated 1 times.
9 is repeated 0 times.
```

here is my code and output so far.

```
#include <stdbool.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{ 
    bool digit_seen[10] = {false};
    int digit;
    long n;


    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%ld", &n);
    while (n > 0) {
      digit = n % 10;
      if (digit_seen[digit])
        break;
      digit_seen[digit] = true;
      n /= 10;
    }

    if (n > 0)
      for(int i=0; i<digit; i++)
        digit_seen[i]++;
      for(int i=0; i<digit; i++)
        printf(" %d is occur %d times \n",i,digit_seen[i]);
    if (n < 0)
      printf("No repeated digit\n");
    return 0;
}
```

here is my output

```
Enter a number: 147795655                                                                                                                                       
 0 is occur 1 times                                                                                                                                             
 1 is occur 1 times                                                                                                                                             
 2 is occur 1 times                                                                                                                                             
 3 is occur 1 times                                                                                                                                             
 4 is occur 1 times
```

as you can see i'm not getting the output i need and i don't understand why.If someone could help me understand where i'm going wrong that would be a big help thanks.

Comment: `bool digit_seen[10] = {false};` --> `int digit_seen[10] = {0};`. Remember: you are counting the occurrences, as in `digit_seen[i]++;`.

Comment: Are negative numbers not allowed to repeat digits?  Why is the last `if(...)` used for?

Answer (score 3):

You're using `bool` values to store which digits exist or which do not, but if you want to count, how many times each digit came, you'll need to use `int` instead of `bool`.

So, define `digit_seen` as:

```
int digit_seen[10] = {0};
```

And change the loop, in which you're calculating the no of digits to this:

```
while (n > 0) {
    digit = n % 10;
    digit_seen[digit]++;
    n /= 10;
}
```

And after that, you can simply print the `digit_seen` array like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    printf(" %d is occur %d times \n",i,digit_seen[i]);
}
```

**EDIT**:

See the [suggested code  in action here](http://ideone.com/sBuooK).

Answer (score 0):

You need two loops - one for counting, and one for printing out the counts.

Since your expected output lists *all* digits, you do not need a separate `digit_seen` loop. You can simply decompose the number with `n%10` and `n/10`, the way you did, and increment `digit_count[digit]` as you go. You need to add a special case for zero, because it's your loop's exit condition.

Answer (score 0):

At the two

```
for(int i=0; i<digit; i++)
```

digit is just the last value got in the while loop, so, the first digit of the number. As well, n exiting value from while will be always 0, so never entering in

```
 if (n > 0)
  for(int i=0; i<digit; i++)
    digit_seen[i]++;
```

neither in

```
 if (n < 0)
  printf("No repeated digit\n");
```

So just entering in

```
 for(int i=0; i<digit; i++)
   printf(" %d is occur %d times \n",i,digit_seen[i]);
```

and then showing if digit is present, or not, in original n number, as shown in your result. 
   You should review your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Your main mistake is that you are trying to increase the elements of a boolean array "bool digit_seen[10]". 
Why don't you try this:

- Declare an integer array[10] initialized with zeroes. Each index of the array will represent a digit and its value will represent its frequency.
- In each iteration of the while loop, *digit = n%10* and then *n = n/10*.
- Every time you do this, increase the corresponding value in your array by one (e.g. *array[digit]++*).
- Then all you have to do is print out the frequencies of the corresponding digits (aka array indices).